# Cookie token authentication login method

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, login-script

There is a method that is using cookies to login users and i don't know it's name. It's setting a unique token to the cookie each time a user logs in. The token is visible and it is set in 1 cookie. There is also a second cookie, which is having a hash in it. Based on these 2 cookies we have:

- the login system is more secure, because each 5 minutes its making a new token and changes the hash value
- this authentication system doesn't require the script to verify users in database each page load. It does it only when it changes the token
- this type of authentication is a persistent one

**Question: what is the name of this method?**

Comment: not gonna post this as an answer since it require reading and a lot of peoples will votedown without reading it.... this is a nice explanation of cookies, usage and such (you might find your answer here) http://www.cse.msu.edu/~alexliu/publications/Cookie/cookie.pdf

Comment: [Persistent Login Cookie Best Practice](http://fishbowl.pastiche.org/2004/01/19/persistent_login_cookie_best_practice/) and [Improved Persistent Login Cookie Best Practice](http://jaspan.com/improved_persistent_login_cookie_best_practice)

Comment: A tip would be to store additional information in the database for validating the token, such as an IP address and user-agent string to add some extra barriers for potential threats. It wouldn't work with attackers on the same network with an identical user-agent string, but it will at least increase the required work.

Comment: Just use print_r($_COOKIE); you will get all the cookie values then you can find out the name of the all the cookies from the browser,,, and if not check out the remember history option ,, or otherwise firebug have a addon thats fire cookie ,, use those tools and get worked

Answer (score 5):

You now procedure pretty well. Name doesn't matter much.

I think you are speaking about: [Remember-Me Authentication](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/remember-me.html)

Answer (score 2):

I think you might be looking for something like OAuth. OAuth has become a sort of "standard" when it comes to token based authentication.

Here's some literature: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5849

I found section **2.3. Token Credentials** particularly similar to what you were talking about...

> The response contains the following REQUIRED parameters:
>
> oauth_token
>
> ```
>     The token identifier.
> ```
>
> oauth_token_secret
>
> ```
>     The token shared-secret.
> ```
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> oauth_token=j49ddk933skd9dks&oauth_token_secret=ll399dj47dskfjdk
> ```

It's also important to note that through my understanding, token based authentication is only more secure if all requests are being made through an SSL connection. If not, 3rd parties can grab and imitate the tokens. So yeah, hope this is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen it referred to as Token Based Authentication. It's a relatively broad term that can apply for other methods than a pure cookie verification, but the principle is the same.